# Binary Tree Recursive Function

Tags: c, recursion, binary-tree

I need to print out a binary tree that looks like this:

```
--------x-------
----x-------x---
--x---x---x---x-
-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x 
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Using recursion to print the left side of the line and the right side of the line with the exception of the first line. So the function would call a display function with parameters of the left starting point and the right ending point. Then it calls itself twice, on for the left side and one for the right.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

#define LENGTH 16

void makeBranches(int, int);
void display(int, int);

int main(){

  makeBranches(0, LENGTH-1);
}

void makeBranches(int left, int right){

  if(left >= right){
    return;
  } else{
    display(left, right);
      makeBranches(left, (right+left)/2);
      makeBranches((right+left)/2+1, right);  
  }
}

void display(int left, int right){
  int mid = (left+right)/2;
  int i;

  for(i = left; i <= right; i++){
    if(i == mid)
      printf("X");
    else
      printf("-");
  }

  if(right == LENGTH-1)
    printf("\n");

}
```

This is currently what my code looks like, although it has changed many times.

I cannot figure out how to get the first call of makeBranches execute and then the second call. Right now it only does the left side calls and looks like this:

```
-------X--------
---X-----X--X-
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see already your problem lies within the structure tree of calling the recursive functions. In order to prevent this type of behavior you need to implement a design where the entire tree is scanned before you print anything out.

Your call structure right now works like this:

```
makeBranches(left,right) -> 
  makeBranches(left, (right+left)/2) ->
    makeBranches(left, ((right+left)/2+left)/2) ->
      makeBranches(left, (((right+left)/2+left)/2+left)/2) -> etc.
  makeBranches((right+left)/2+1,right) ->
    makeBranches((right+(right+left)/2+1)/2+1,right) ->
      makeBranches((right+(right+(right+(right+left)/2+1)/2+1)/2+1)/2+1,right) -> etc.
```

In order to flatten this out what you should be aiming to do is capture each level before printing. To do this you'll need some form of collection like a Linked List to add to for each side, then once the entire tree is scanned you can reconstruct the drawing.

Within your `display` function you've already created a check to know if this is a left or right side of the line:

```
if(right == LENGTH-1)
    printf("\n");
```

So let's modify the display call.

```
void display(int left, int right){
  int mid = (left+right)/2;
  int i;
  string thisLine = "";

  for(i = left; i <= right; i++){
    if(i == mid)
      thisLine += "X";
    else
      thisLine += "-";
  }

  if(right == LENGTH-1) {
    rightList.add(thisLine);
  } else {
    leftList.add(thisLine);
  }
}
```

Now, from your `main()` after the entire tree is constructed print out every node of each list going `left->right->"\n"` (repeat until empty).

Some caveats you can watch out for, but could design around are the fact that your very first call to `display` creates the entire line so if you used my code it'd drop it on the `right` list meaning you'd have to draw it like `right->(left->right->"\n")repeat`

Does this make sense? I hope I didn't skip out on anything as I did this all conceptually :\

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a [breadth-first traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).